# Increment internal counter variable inside for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

So, that's the question: can I increment the `i` variable inside `for` loop?:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    i++; // is this legal? if not what is the alternative?
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly legal. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, it somehow doesn't work, maybe i'm doing something wrong... But the purpose of the question was to ask if it is a good practice to do so, if it's possible.

Comment: What doesn't work? Maybe update your question with what seems to be unexpected about the resulting behaviour.

Comment: It's legal, but it is meant exceptional processing probably.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try to debug a bit more time, if I don't manage to get it working I'll post the broken code.

Comment: Great. Good luck getting it working!

Comment: If you're just looking to increment twice, you could also do `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 2)`

Comment: If you want e.g. to skip some `i`, then you could also use `continue`.

Comment: OK, thanks guys, I went the `while` approach, it really seems to be more intuitive in this situation. But I also managed to implement my code with `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely legal but not very intuitive.

Consider using a while loop instead if you need to manipulate your looping in this way (it's just a code clarity thing, not a legal thing).

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the C99 draft standard it says the following about the *for* loop in section `6.8.5.3` *The for statement*:

> The statement
>
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression expression-3 is
>   evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a
>   declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and
>   the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution
>   before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.<sup>137)</sup>

So if we parse this text your *for* loop will be roughly equivalent to the following:

```
{
   int i = 0 ;  // clause 1
   while( i < 1000 ) //expression 2
   {
         i++ ; // statement

         i++ ; // expression 3
   }      
}
```

which is valid code but you would probably not write the code this way if you translated it out by hand.